# Reverse reshaping of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a time series **t** composed of 30 features, with a shape of `(5400, 30)`. To plot it and identify the anomalies I had to reshape it in the following way:

```
t = t[:,0].reshape(-1)
```

Now, it became a single tensor of shape `(5400,)` where I had the possibility to perform my analysis and create a list of 5400 elements composed of True and False, based on the position of the anomalies:

```
anomaly = [True, False, True, ...., False]
```

Now I would like to reshape this list of a size `(30, 5400)` (the reverse of the first one). How can I do that?

EDIT: this is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
I have a time series of size `(2, 4)`

```
feature 1 | feature 2 | feature 3 | feature 4
  0.3         0.1        0.24          0.25
  0.62        0.45       0.43          0.9
```

Coded as:

```
[[0.3, 0.1, 0.24, 0.25]
[0.62, 0.45, 0.43, 0.9]]
```

When I reshape it I get this univariate time series of size (8,):

```
[0.3, 0.1, 0.24, 0.25, 0.62, 0.45, 0.43, 0.9]
```

On this time series I applied an anomaly detection method which gave me a list of True/False for each value:

```
[True, False, True, False, False, True, True, False]
```

I wanna make this list of the reverse of the shape of the original one, so it would be structured as:

```
feature 1 True, False 
feature 2 False, True
feature 3 True, True
feature 4 False, False
```

with a shape of (4, 2), so coded it should be:

```
[[True, False]
[False, True]
[True, True]
[False, False]]
```

Comment: How do you reshape 5400 to (30, 5400)? And why?

Comment: is it sufficient to transpose the original collection?

Comment: @QuangHoang I haven't reshaped it yet. At the moment I have only the list of 5400 True/False for each observation. I need to make that list of shape (30, 5400)

Comment: your question has ambiguity. you are reassigning t to t[:,0].reshape(-1). give us clear inputs and be clear about what you want.

Comment: My question is, say what does your output look like? E.g. what's `output[0]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I updated the question

Comment: `t[:,0]` selects one column of `t`.  Its shape is `((5400,)`, no need to reshape (check it).  You can't go back to the whole `t` shape because you've "thrown-away" 29 columns.  This selection is just a subset of the original.  But the EDIT suggests that you are doing `t.reshape(-1)`, 'flattening' the WHOLE array, not just one column.

Comment: @Fabio it is still unclear what do you want in your (30,5400) array. Do you want to repeat the same 'anomaly' column 30 times?

Comment: You need to construct a small example, say with a `t` that is (10,5), and be very clear what you intend to do.  With the (5400,30) array you can only talk in generalities and show pieces.  There's too much room for ambiguity.  Plus any good answer will show that it works with a real example.

Comment: @hpaulj I edit the question and the example

Comment: [[0.3, 0.1, 0.24, 0.25]
[0.62, 0.45, 0.43, 0.9]] is a (2,4) array not a (8,4) array

Comment: @Murali Just corrected, thanks

Comment: You can use `.reshape(number_of_features, -1)`. However, I would reframe the problem to avoid flattening in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = np.array([[0.3, 0.1, 0.24, 0.25],[0.62, 0.45, 0.43, 0.9]])
anomaly= [True, False, True, False, False, True, True, False]
your_req_array = np.array(anomaly).reshape(2,4).T
```